# Not able to access a variable (created in a child frame) from the root window

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to create an application where the user enters a directory name and it gets printed in the console. For this I have created 2 classes:

```
class FolderInputFrame(tk.Frame):
    ## child frame class
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self._widgets()
        self.pack()

    def _widgets(self):        
        self.directory = tk.StringVar()

        buttonDir = tk.Button(self, text = 'Source Directory: ', command = self.browse_button)
        buttonDir.pack(side = 'left', padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
        dirEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.directory, width = 70)
        dirEntry.pack(side = 'left', padx = 10, pady = 10)

    def browse_button(self):
        dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='/', title='Please select a directory')
        self.directory.set(dirname)
        print(self.directory.get())      ## directory string from child class

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    ## root class
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.folder_input_container  = FolderInputFrame(self)
        print(self.folder_input_container.directory.get())     ## directory string from root class
```

Now when I am trying to print the directory string from the 2 classes, the child class shows the appropriate directory entered, but the root class shows an empty output. I am confused why this is happening? I am fairly new to Tkinter, so any help is appreciated here.

I was expecting the strings from both root and child class should have been same after the button is pressed. I need to know how the flow of control is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the data from the instance of the `FolderInputFrame` since that is the class that created the variable:

```
print(self.folder_input_container.directory.get())
```

You need to make sure you do this *after* the user has clicked the button. In your example you're attempting to print the value immediately after creating the instance of `FolderInputFrame`.

Use this modified version of `MainWindow` to see that the value has been updated. After selecting the directory, click the "Show Directory" button to have it print the value to the console.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    ## root class
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.folder_input_container  = FolderInputFrame(self)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Print Directory", command=self.print_directory)
        button.pack()

    def print_directory(self):
        print(f"directory: {self.folder_input_container.directory.get()}")
```

Comment: The first part of the answer where I missed to use the instance of the class in calling its variable is a mistake in typing, I have corrected the question now. My problem is with the second part of your answer: after the user presses the button, the string doesn't get updated. Any idea/ suggestion with a code example how I can implement your idea. Thanks for pointing the mistake and the valuable help.

Comment: @SayanB6292: when I modify your code to add a button I can click to print the value from the other class, the value is printed just as I expect.

Comment: This is a nice idea, implementing a button from the MainWindow class solves it. Thanks for the help!